# Match a string containing no newlines, unless the newline is preceded by double backslash

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture a substring that doesn't contain any `\n` characters, *unless* such character is preceded by `\\`. The substring is finally followed by a `\n` (which I don't want to capture). This is the regex I've tried:

```
([^(?<!\\\\)\n]+)\n
```

This isn't quite working as expected. I would expect two negations to result in a positive match, but it's not happening. Encountering a `\n` will cause the capture group to be broken out of, even if it is preceded by `\\`.

What's the correct approach in my case?

Comment: Try `\A.*(?:\\\n.*)*\z`. If it is JavaScript/ECMAScript, try `/^.*(?:\\\r?\n.*)*$/`

Comment: Can you please give example of what should be matched and not matched with regex needed?

Comment: Given the string `"blahblah\\\nblah blah\n abc"`, I want to capture `"blahblah\\\nblah blah"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
/^.*[^\\\n](?:\\\n.*[^\\\n])*$/m
/^.*(?:(?<=\\)\n.*)*$/m
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YnYNbZ/1). `m` flag makes `^` and `$` match line end positions.

*Regex details*:

- `^` - line start
- `.*[^\\\n]` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a char other than `\` and newline
- `(?:\\\n.*[^\\\n])*` - zero or more sequences of `\`, line feed char and then zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a char other than `\` and newline
- `.*(?:(?<=\\)\n.*)*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then zero or more sequences of a line feed char that is immediately preceded with a `\` and then zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of line.